# I'm unable to print the text in TextView that i'm getting from the EditText under the TextInputLayout

Tags: android

```
EditText etName = view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
 Button bSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
    TextView set = view.findViewById(R.id.set);

 String name = etName.getText().toString();

 bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           set.setText(name);
       }
   });
```

Unable to get text from EditText and print that in TextView...

Comment: Does this code give you any errors?

Comment: tell me one thing first, How could you able to use set inside anonymous class without final?

Comment: I guess you are missing the typecast for your views. Like `EditText etName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etName);`

Comment: @Saikat1529 Down casting is optional  in latest build tool versions. So it can be used directly .

Comment: @ADM oh thanks for your information. I never knew about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the data inside the click listner

```
bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String name = etName.getText().toString();
           set.setText(name);
       }
   });
```

Comment: Worked bro... Thnks

Comment: very happy to help you.. :)

Comment: can u please explain why the previous one not worked ?  @BenjithMathew

Comment: **Read the data when you want.!**
Previously your are reading data before itself and that variable is not static also that's why you didn't get data inside anonymous class.
Make this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the name `final`:

```
final TextView set = view.findViewById(R.id.set);
final String name = etName.getText().toString();

bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        set.setText(name);
    }
});
```

I'm not certain if your current code even compiles, but the general pattern to follow is that only final variables are available to the handler methods of listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Declare 'name' as final, rest is fine.

```
final TextView set = view.findViewById(R.id.set);
final String name = etName.getText().toString();
```

Or you may define 'name' & 'set' as a field variable.